# Devise + Facebook - Accessing user information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise

I'm using Devise and can currently allow the user to log in via Facebook, but I'd like to get some extra information (basically anything that's public - work experience, school, etc) if it's available. I have this in my Applicant model:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  applicant = Applicant.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless applicant
    applicant = Applicant.create(
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                         )
  end
  logger.debug auth
  applicant
end
```

I can see the information I want in the auth model, but I'm not sure how to get at it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: instead of logger.debug, try to use debugger and start your server with --debugger. Then you will be droped in a console. Try to access what you need with auth["data"] or auth.data. Learn how to identify an object, array or hash in the console.

Answer (score 0):

To get the email you probably want to use `auth['info']['email']`.